# iPhone devices don't connect to Local server in App

Tags: ios, mysql, swift2, localhost, afnetworking

I set up a a local server on my `iOS` app using `AFNetworking` and it works fine when I'm using my `simulator` but when I plug in my iPhone I get an `error: cannot connect to server`

```
func postStripeToken(token: STPToken) {

    let URL = "http://localhost/donate/payment.php"
    let params  : [String: AnyObject] =  ["stripeToken": token.tokenId,
                                          "amount": totalPrice,
                                          "currency": "usd",
                                          "description": self.emailTextField.text!]

    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = true;

    manager.POST(URL, parameters: params, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in

        if let response = responseObject as? [String: String] {
            UIAlertView(title: response["status"],
                message: response["message"],
                delegate: nil,
                cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
```

This is the code where I get the error. I tried changing `localhost` to my computers `IP` address but that did not resolve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem, solved by using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost (using emulator, on real device need to use computer ip)

Answer (score 3):

When a url contains 'localhost' (`"http://localhost/donate/payment.php"`) it means the current device, therefore you are trying to access your server on your iphone, instead of on the network. Use your servers ip instead of localhost in the url (make sure you are on the same network as well) you may need to add your servers port number to the url that it uses eg "http://192.168.0.10:8080/donate/payment.php"

Comment: I tried that using my Ip address and my MySQL port which was 3305 and the error i get is Please Try Again "Could Not Connect to Server"

Comment: can you access that URL from your browser on your phone? if not then its the wrong port most likely (try without the port number as well), not sure what you are using to host your server, but could try 8080, as its a very common port to use.

Comment: now I just use my IP address and it works on my simulator and it works on my device but it only works on my device when I'm connected to wifi. Does this mean its only possible to access my server on my wifi or is it just a connection issue?

Comment: heh when i said "(make sure you are on the same network as well)" i meant your server and phone should both be on your wifi/ethernet. if your phone is using your mobile data, that means its trying to access your internal network from the internet, and then you would have to setup port forwarding on your router etc which is a hassle. if you are planning to use this server as your actual server to serve clients from the internet you will have to port forward on your router. for now i suggest just using your wifi and you can figure that out later (its not difficult but i dont want to explain it)

Comment: Awesome! That is a huge help for me(someone who has no experience with servers)